# How to use doSwitch properly in a scearioBuilder

Tags: scala, gatling

My scenario builder below does not like the variable ${data} in the doSwitch.
Result in error:

Expected type was: (Any, io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder)
.doSwitch("${data}")

What is causing the issue?

```
      val builder: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Test")
        .repeat(3) {
          pace(10.seconds)
            .feed(new DataFeeder())
            .exec { session =>
              val data = session("data").as[String]
              println(s"data: $data")
              session
            }
            .doSwitch("${data}") {
              // Define cases for different data values
              case "P1" =>
                exec(myFunc(1000000))
              case "P2" =>
                exec(myFunc(2000000))
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs of [doSwitch](https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/scenario/#doswitch) you have the following example of code

> ```scala
> doSwitch("#{myKey}")( // beware: use parentheses, not curly braces!
>   "foo" -> exec(http("name1").get("/foo")),
>   "bar" -> exec(http("name2").get("/bar"))
> )
> ```

where the second parameter is between parentheses `( )` and not curly braces `{ }`. The comment in the code says don't use curly braces.

mean while you are doing this

```scala
            .doSwitch("${data}") {
              // Define cases for different data values
              case "P1" =>
                exec(myFunc(1000000))
              case "P2" =>
                exec(myFunc(2000000))
            }
```

you are using curly braces and then adding `case` followed by a value, then `=>` (instead of `->`) and finally `exec(...)`

Your should be similar to

```scala
            .doSwitch("${data}") (
              // Define cases for different data values
              "P1" -> exec(myFunc(1000000))
              "P2" -> exec(myFunc(2000000))
            )
```